# how to retrieve sub documents associated in mongoDB using _id (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

**i was trying to retrieve data associated with the id,and store it in a variable.
my database looks like**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5ebc4242c2098c7968853b44"),  //userId
"firstname" : "john", 
"lastname" : "Jacob", 
"username" : "john@abc.com", 
"comments" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd124e7f92505c9c23b680"),  
        "comment" : "hey there", 
        "imagename" : "image-1589449294815.PNG"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ebd24b9cae2ab15683460ed"), 
        "comment" : "whazup", 
        "imagename" : "image-1589454009062.jpeg"
    }
```

**i was retrieving back the particular id(of the image that was selected via checkbox),and want to access the particular comment and associated image name(through id) and then send the image  to my .ejs file via SIMG**

**app.js looks like**

```
app.post("/checkout", uploads, function (req, res) {
  User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, foundUser) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (foundUser) {
const uid = foundUser.id; //this is users id.
var checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox; // this is checked image id.

    User.findById(checkedItemId, function (err, foundID) {
      if (foundID) {
        console.log(foundID);
        console.log(foundID.comment);
        console.log(foundID.imagename);

        res.render("checkout", {
          SIMG: imagename,
        });
      }
    });
    if (Array.isArray(req.body.checkbox)) {
          res.render("checkout", {
            SIMG: req.body.checkbox,
          });
        } else {
          res.render("checkout", {
            SIMG: [req.body.checkbox],
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**i was using the above findById method,but it seems its not working,or i may not be using the proper method.**

**schema looks like**

```
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  comment: String,
  imagename: String,
});

const Comment = new mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  comments: [commentSchema],
});



const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: Post the code of Schema

Comment: hii,i have edited the code above to add schema. thanks

Comment: so you need to get the comment that only match the checkedItemId?, also this checkedItemId should represent the comment._id or what?

Comment: What is type _id?

Comment: yes,i need to get both,the comment aswell as the image name,associated with checkedItemId. when i log checkedItemId i am getting the id value( example "5ebd124e7f92505c9c23b680" in above senerio i am able to log via checkedItemid,but i want comment ie. ""hey there" and its associated image name ie.  "image-1589449294815.PNG" ) @mohammedyousry

Comment: type _id is object id. @soham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findById` method is used to get documents by their `_id`, so when you pass `checkedItemId` to `User.findById(checkedItemId)` it will return nothing, as this `checkedItemId` is not a `userId`, it's the commentId

you can get the `comment` that has this `checkedItemId` by doing some code after the first `User.findById(req.user.id)`

something like this

```
app.post("/checkout", uploads, function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, foundUser) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (foundUser) {
                const uid = foundUser.id; //this is users id.
                var checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox; // this is checked image id.

                // this will return only the comments that have the same id as checkedItemId, 
                // it should be one 

                foundUser.comments = foundUser.comments.filter((comment) => { comment._id.toString() === checkedItemId.toString() });
                // now you have comments array inside the user object, but this comments array is filtered 

                // If you need to get the image name of that comment, we know that this array has only one element as the id is unique,
                // so we can use comments[0] to get the imagename
                var imagename = foundUser.comments[0].imagename;

                // do the res.render here

                if (Array.isArray(req.body.checkbox)) {
                    res.render("checkout", {
                        SIMG: req.body.checkbox,
                    });
                } else {
                    res.render("checkout", {
                        SIMG: [req.body.checkbox],
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

there is another way to get only the comment that match the `checkedItemId` directly from the query, using aggregate pipeline with $filter

```
app.post("/checkout", uploads, function (req, res) {
    User.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                firstname: 1,
                lastname: 1,
                username: 1,
                comments: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$comments',
                        as: 'comment',
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ['$$comment._id', mongoose.Types.ObjectId(checkedItemId)]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]).exec().then(function (users) { // the aggregate is returning an array

        console.log(users); // this users should have only one document as the user id is unique I guess
        // this document has a comments array with only one comment as the comment id is unique too

        // here you can do the render

    });
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to get the object using aggregate pipeline method by changing the checkedItemId to req.body.checkbox.